# Laravel Json response exception

Tags: laravel, exception, error-handling, jsonresponse

How to throw a json response error in laravel outside the controller or any part of the application?

something like that

throw new ConflictException('any')

Answer (score 0):

you throw your exceptions and then laravel handle it automatically for Json or web
when you use accept:application/json in request param